# Can we get meaningful stats for the "Launched proposals" tab in the Area51 homepage?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, user-interface, statistics

At present, the [launched proposals tab in the Area51 homepage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) looks like this:

[image]

On the right, it shows progress bars showing that the site has gone through `Definition`, `Commitment` and `Beta` phases. But of what use is this? We all know that it needs to go through these stages before it gets launched and showing that it in fact has, is rather redundant. Those bars are not even clickable! It would make perhaps an iota of sense if clicking the different stages actually took you to the corresponding stage for the site.

I would request that these pointless bars be replaced with some at-a-glance stats, such as `#of Questions`, `#of Answers`, `traffic`, `#of users`, etc. (how much ever fits in that space), similar to https://stackexchange.com/sites. This would help users "gauge" the success of each site (or interpret them in whatever way they wish).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those public launched sites have been shot off in a rocket into space and are far, far away from Area 51 now.

Their stats are on the network homepage:

https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

I don't see the need for Area 51 to fold this in, since it is primarily focused on the **BETA** process of getting sites healthy enough to launch. Once they've fully **left beta** and launched as final public sites, they have run the entire Area 51 gauntlet (successfully!), "left the planet" and should be tracked elsewhere.

Comment: that is fine. It's just that those "progress bars" seem to convey information when they actually are not. Simply removing them would suffice too :) I'm marking this accepted because whichever way you decide to proceed, it's too minor of an issue for me to press on if I disagree. I'll save my mana for other stuff :)

Comment: where can we see the number of visits per day for each site just like in area51?